# iAd & AdWhirl? Or Just one of them?

Tags: iphone, iad

I currently have iAds working in my app... but, since I'm looking to support iPhone 3.x as well... is it worth it to implement and set up AdWhirl?

Or is the market share for 3.x vs 4.x not worth much? Anyone have any stats around this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is potentially related: [Using iAd as default ad network, and AdMob if iAd fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632032/using-iad-as-default-ad-network-and-admob-if-iad-fails)

Comment: As far as OS adoption statistics, that question keeps getting asked.  The most recent question can be found here: [iPhone/iPod Touch Version Statistics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074033/iphone-ipod-touch-version-statistics)

Comment: Thank you! These links are perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether you support 3.X or not I'd recommend using AdWhirl. You can read [my blog post on why](http://www.neilinglis.com/2010/07/20/using-adwhirl-to-achieve-high-fill-rates/) but to summarise

1) iAds are currently only available in US and UK. You'll want to pull in another supplier for different countries.
2) iAds only supply a fill rate of maybe 10% if you're lucky. That means 9 out of 10 times you don't get an advert. In these cases you want AdWhirl to go get you another one.

If go iAd only then you'll lose out on a lot of revenue.

Comment: Thanks Neillnglis! I'll check out your post.

Answer (score 3):

**Note :** Now AdWhirl is not working.
now you can use **AdMob mediation**

Best tutorial of AdMob mediation

[AdMob_Mediation_Demo](https://github.com/111vandana/AdMob_Demo/archive/master.zip)

You can download it and use it in your project

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [mopub](http://www.mopub.com/) instead of AdWhirl. It  has support for a lot of ad networks built in, without having to add more SDKs to your app, and server side there are a lot of switches and knobs you can tweak to fine tune your ad display.