# How to integrate iAds and AdMob if iAds fails

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob, iad

I have been searching around for a little while looking for a complete guide on how to integrate iAds with AdMobs if iAds fails,

The only reason I ask this is that I have iAds and I am noticing a very low fill rate with iAds and would love to have AdMobs fill the spaces. I have read the related post below and feel this is a little outdated (from 2010)

are there any better solutions complete tutorial out there with detailed code that you know about.

[Using iAd as default ad network, and AdMob if iAd fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632032/using-iad-as-default-ad-network-and-admob-if-iad-fails)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a Mediation solution.  One example is [AdMob Mediation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation).  All you need to do is write code against the AdMob API, plug in the iAd adapter library (available [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/ad-network-mediation)), and configure a Mediation placement to request iAd and backfill AdMob.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  these controls to show iAds as well as adMob both

```
https://github.com/pjcook/iAdPlusAdMob
https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController
```

Or here is nice tut that explain step by step

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/supplementing-iad-placement-with-admob/