# iAd and admob integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, admob, iad

I added an iAd ad to my app with Swift language:

```
    var adBannerView: ADBannerView?
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
        func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
self.adBannerView?.hidden = false
}
func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
}
```

Now I want to add an Admob too for reaching more countries and for better fill rate, but admob code for iOS is in Objective - C...
How can I show an admob ad when iAd fails?

Comment: Put it in the `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` delegate method.

Comment: This it's my implementation to synchronise iAd and ADMob:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31802853/2553454

Answer (score 0):

Use iOS (swift-objective C bridging concept) to use admob in your swift application.
Follow this link for how to use objective C code in swift.

[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

In the iAd delegate function below, add code to load GAd

```
    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error:      NSError!) {

}
```